# My Mp3 Cd won't work on my computer

Tags: windows-7, mp3, hp-elitebook

I have a Windows 7 "EliteBook" and am trying to rip the songs off of an Mp3 onto iTunes but it won't let me. It tells me that it is a blank cd. I know there are songs on there because it was double checked for the songs when it was first burned. What can I do to fix this?!

Comment: Wait, you're trying to rip a data CD?

Comment: Burned CDs do degrade over time. If it was burned a long time ago, the data may be lost.

Comment: Can you check the CD on some other device ?